# Download file returned by ajax

Tags: ajax, file, yii

I am showing file names in a gridView. I have used a link for the file name. When user clicks the filename the file should be downloaded. For this I used ajax in javascript to send parameters to controller.
In my controller action I am using code

```
readfile( Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot.order files').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$order->user_id.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$_GET['id'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$_GET['file']);
    Yii::app()->end();
```

But the result is returned as a string in response. 
Is there a way to download file from the returned string? I know file cant be downloaded from the string, i am just asking some way to download file using ajax.

Comment: `window.location = url_to_controller;`?  not ajax but much easier.

Comment: yes it is easier but it redirects the page, means complete round trip, which i dont want.

Comment: actually i let the user to download many files from gridView so user can click on same page many times.

Comment: if you set the http headers to force a download it will not redirect the page